# Why does the value of "Device Location" of the USB port change?

Tags: windows, c#, ports

Why does the value of "Device Location" of the USB port change?

I use `USBClassLibrary`:

```
static List<string> UsbValues(string vid, string pid) {
    var ListOfUSBDeviceProperties = new List<USBClass.DeviceProperties>();
    var USBPort = new USBClass();
    var list = new List<string>();

    if(USBClass.GetUSBDevice(uint.Parse(vid, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier), uint.Parse(pid, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier), ref ListOfUSBDeviceProperties, false, null)) {

        for (int i = 0; i < ListOfUSBDeviceProperties.Count; i++) {
            list.Add(ListOfUSBDeviceProperties[i].DeviceLocation);
        }

    }

    return list;
}
```

This returns: Port_#0002.Hub_#0009, but this value can suddenly change to another, for example Port_#0001.Hub_#0010.

Why is this happening? Maybe there's another way to bind a physical device?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that port and hub value changes without you unplugging the device or a hub and plugging it in again to a different port?

Comment: @diidu i connect device to port 1, read location(port 1 hub 10), and disconnect. Then many times i connect and disconnect device from this port (port 1) and location not changed. But it happens that I again connect to this port (port 1) and the location is changed to another. Why might this happen?

Comment: Strange. Would it be possible that the device is normally enumerated as high speed but when the port changes, as full or low speed? Or vice versa?

Comment: I don't think I am able to help with this one. But I recommend you use USB View to see which hub and port the device is connected to at different times: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560019(v=vs.85).aspx